# Sonarqube "Failed to create an empty directory" when scanning multiple projects in one VSTS build definition

Tags: sonarqube, azure-pipelines

I need to run sonarqube for multiple projects in a nightly build definition. The problem I found is - after successfully run sonarqube for the first project, a `.sonarqube` folder is created and a process seems keep using the folder. As a result, the folder cannot be deleted / used by subsequent projects. Is there a way to solve this?

[image]

Error in the prepare step of 2nd project:

```
2017-06-08T22:43:53.0910761Z ##[error]Failed to create an empty directory 'C:\VSTS-Agent-2.104.0\_work\3\.sonarqube'. Please check that there are no open or read-only files in the directory and that you have the necessary read/write permissions.
2017-06-08T22:43:53.0910761Z ##[error]Detailed error message: The process cannot access the file 'newSummaryReport.md' because it is being used by another process.
2017-06-08T22:43:53.0910761Z ##[error]Pre-processing failed. Exit code: 1
2017-06-08T22:43:53.0910761Z ##[error]System.Exception: Unexpected exit code received from batch file: 1
2017-06-08T22:43:53.0910761Z    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.InvokeBatchScriptCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
2017-06-08T22:43:53.0910761Z    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
2017-06-08T22:43:53.1066882Z ##[error]PowerShell script completed with 1 errors.
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue, try to delete 3 folder (_work\3) and try again. Also, try again with another build agent and check the result. On the other hand, you can share the detail build log on the OneDrive.

Comment: I can constantly reproduce the issue but seems the process/file-lock is temporary. Say project 2's sonarqube failed, project 3's would be okay. I am thinking to add a powershell script in between to wait for the release of file lock. I guess this could be related to project size?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with the simple projects? What's the size of these projects?

Comment: I too am encountering this issue.

Comment: I have the same problem with onprem TFS 2018.

Comment: I met a similar issue in DevOps Server 2020u1 with SonarQube extension 4.21.0, running against SonarQube Enterprise 8.9.1 (build 44547), using SonarScanner for MSBuild 5.2.1. The message was not about .sonarqube folder itself, it was about .sonarqube/out. Second run of the pipeline on the specific agent always fails, first one succeeds. Deleting the .sonarqube folder via a task at the top of the pipeline helped. This GitHub issue seems to describe my issue: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-msbuild/issues/939

Answer (score 4):

I bypass this issue:

- by adding a delete file task to pipeline before `"Prepare analysis on SonarQube"` task;
- delete `".sonarqube\out\"` folder. Source folder `"$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\.sonarqube\out\"`;
- be sure to check `"Remove files starting with a dot"` in advance.